# WP Query sort by meta value

Tags: sort, meta-value

I would like to get posts order by timestamps. I have to following code but the query keeps getting posts order by modification dates and not with the "evcal_srow" meta. Any clue?

```
<ul class="slides-container">
<?php 
    $args = array(
       'post_type'  =>  'events',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'meta_key'   =>  'evcal_srow',              
       'order'      =>  'ASC',
       'order_by'   =>  'meta_value_num',         
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            $the_query->the_post(); 
            $timestamp = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'evcal_srow', true );
            $le_jour = strftime ("%A %d %B %Y", $timestamp);
            $l_heure = strftime ("%H:%M", $timestamp);
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'event_type' );
    ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
            <?php $soustitre = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'evcal_subtitle', true ); ?>
            <h3><?php echo $soustitre;?></h3>
            <h2><?php echo $le_jour." - ".$l_heure;?></h2>
            <?php  
                if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                    $level = array();
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $level[] = $term->name;
                    }         
                $levelmini = join( ", ", $level );
            ?>
                <h4>
                    Niveau Minimum: <span><?php echo $levelmini; ?></span>
                </h4>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible issue is regarding the date format. How about the solution in [_this_ thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404134/1743124)?

Comment: It‘s orderby, not order_by